# Функция, которая сможет работать как метод

Tags: python, python-3.x

Хочу сделать что то вроде `2000000002.getInfo()`, который возвращал бы информацию по коду. Возможно ли это? В гугле не нашел ничего.

Comment: Никак, встроенным типам (целым числам в данном случае) не получится привязать какой-то свой метод.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам придется создать класс

```
class Number:
    def __init__(self, num):
        this.num = num

    def getInfo():
        #какой-то код
```

и создать его экземпляр. Иначе наверное никак